# Can we disable iCloud App services in Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, icloud, provisioning-profile

I need to work on iCloud feature for a testing purpose. I can enable iCloud App Services in an existing App ID and create new provisional files. 
My question is, Can we able to disable iCloud option in the Apple Developer account for that particular App ID once my test is done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable iCloud for an application ID after you have enabled it.  To do so, go to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" area of the Apple developer site.  Go to where you have defined your app IDs.  Find the app ID for the app you have done iCloud testing on.  Edit the app ID, and deselect the iCloud check box.  It will notify you that it will invalidate any provisioning profiles associated with that app ID.

[image: iCloud disable confirmation dialog]

This means you will then need to go re-generate your development and distribution profiles after you have done this.  U?ntil you do that, you will not be able to build your app.  Regenerate the provisioning profiles and any new versions of the app that build with the new provisioning profiles will not be able to use iCloud.